# We have a box with 100 screws (90 good 10 defective). What is the prob. that we choose 10 non-defective?

Tags: probability

Probability to choose a non-defective screw for the 1st time is $\dfrac{90}{100}$

2nd time $\dfrac{89}{99}$

3rd time $\dfrac{88}{98}$

...

10th time $\dfrac{81}{91}$

The final result is a multiplication of these probabilities. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes.  This is correct.

Comment: Correct assuming that we are drawing without replacement.